# What is the correct way to set credentials for a directory when using EC2Launch sysprep?

Tags: amazon-ami, sysprep

I created a startup script like this:

```
$FolderPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Directory"
$UserAccount = "Domain\User" # Replace with the appropriate user or group
$Acl = Get-Acl $FolderPath
$AccessRule = New-Object 
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($UserAccount, "FullControl", 
"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") # Replace 'FullControl' with the desired permission level
$Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $FolderPath $Acl
```

and set it to run in `Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) > Startup > Powershell`

But when I run `EC2Launch sysprep` the EC2 instance loses file permissions for `Domain\User` in `C:\Path\To\Your\Directory`. Specifically I am trying to get IIS to host a website out of either `C:\users\admin\desktop\public` or `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot` so for tests I am giving `Everyone` `Full Control` on both of those directories. IIS hosts the sites before I do `EC2Launch sysprep` but after the permissions are gone. As one further test I go ahead and create an AMI after running `EC2Launch sysprep` and use that AMI for the Auto Scaling Group in an elastic beanstalk environment and it doesn't work there either.

Am I setting directory permissions for a user correctly? What account is it running under when it executes my scripts? Maybe that account needs to be ran as admin?

Basically though, I'm hoping someone knows the right way to give `Domain\User` access to `C:\Path\To\Your\Directory` in an AMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the permissions in the startup script, you can set them using the `EC2Launch` configuration file, because EC2Launch sysprep can reset settings when run.

First go create a `powershell` ( dont forget to replace the `YourDomain` and `YourUser` )

```
script $FolderPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Directory"
$DomainName = "YourDomain"
$UserName = "YourUser"
$UserAccount = "$DomainName\$UserName"
$Acl = Get-Acl $FolderPath
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($UserAccount, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $FolderPath $Acl
```

then we go to `Ec2LaunchSettings.ps1` located at `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Script` and add this at the end (`Path\To\Your\Script.ps1` is the path of the script we created just before )

```
& "C:\Path\To\Your\Script.ps1"
```

then we save `Ec2LaunchSettings.ps1` , now you can re run `EC2Launch` sysprep, it should work.

Comment: FYI while this didn't get me all the way there it did point in the right direction. After another two days of pulling my hair out reading AWS documentation and not getting anywhere I switched to Azure. Not saying it's less difficult to work with but anyways. ...i might have been able to do it without ever running sysprep. which would have been nice because despite the 10 ways i tried userdata NEVER WORKED. If using azure apparantly you dont have to while if using AWS their official instructions are to generalize. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/capture-image-portal